# AWS S3 with Java - Reactive: S3 upload doesn't work

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-batch, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Spring Batch that should get a gzipped file from a rest service and then save it in a S3 bucket in the first step. In the second step it should retrieve this file from S3 and elaborate it. I have tried to follow [this guide](https://baeldung-cn.com/java-aws-s3-reactive) ("Single File Upload" case).

I'm able to save the file in S3, but I get "NoSuchKeyException: The specified key does not exist." at the beginning of the second step.

Looking at S3 bucket, the file has been written just 2 seconds after the second step started. It seems that the first step said "file created" even if its process was not completed. Infact this log:

```
log.info("S3 saving response: {}", response.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful());
```

is not present at all in the logs.

Thanks in advance!

The tasklet of the first step (simplified):

```
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        
        ...
        
        Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> response = myService.getAnalyticsDataBuffer2(authToken);
        response.log().map(e -> {
            DataBufferMapper dataBufferMapper = new DataBufferMapper(myFileManager, analyticTripFilename);
            return dataBufferMapper.apply(e);
        }).log().block();
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
```

The method to retrieve the gzipped file:

```
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> getAnalyticsDataBuffer2(String correlationId, String token) {
        return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(
                uriBuilder ->
                    uriBuilder.path(ANALITYCS)
                        .build()
            )
            .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(token))
            .header("Business-User-Id", clientId)
            .header("Connection", "close")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntityFlux(DataBuffer.class)

            .name(METRICS_NAME)
            .tag(TAG_API_NAME, API_NAME)
            .metrics();
    }
```

The mapper Functional interface:

```
public class DataBufferMapper implements Function<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>, Mono> {

    private final MyFileManager myFileManager;
    private final String analyticTripFilename;

    public DataBufferMapper(MyFileManager myFileManager, String analyticTripFilename) {
        this.myFileManager = myFileManager;
        this.analyticTripFilename = analyticTripFilename;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono apply(ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>> response) {
        return myFileManager.saveFile(analyticTripFilename, response.getBody(), response.getHeaders().getContentLength());
    }
}
```

The implementation of the S3 upload.

```
public class S3FileManager implements MyFileManager {

    @Autowired
    private S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient;

    @Autowired
    private S3ClientConfig s3ClientConfig;

    @Override
    public Mono saveFile(String fileName, Flux<DataBuffer> body, long contentLength) {
        log.info("S3FileManager saving file/content length{}/{}", fileName, contentLength);
        Flux<java.nio.ByteBuffer> buffers = body.map(DataBuffer::asByteBuffer);
        CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> future = s3AsyncClient. putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(s3ClientConfig.getBucket())
            .contentLength(contentLength)
            .key(fileName)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.toString())
            .build(), AsyncRequestBody.fromPublisher(buffers));

        return Mono.fromFuture(future)
            .map(response -> {
                checkResult(response);
                log.info("S3 saving response: {}", response.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful());
                return response;
            });
    }
```

**Update**

To isolate the problem, I have added reactor logs and added a 'local' implementation for `MyFileManager` like this:

```
    @Override
    public Mono saveFile(String fileName, Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer, long contentLength) {
        String filePath = localFileManagerPath + fileName;
        final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
        log.info("LocalFileManager saving {}", filePath);
        return DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, path, CREATE_NEW).log();
    }
```

Now the error is clearly  turned into 'Input resource must exist' and the log says:

```
[ INFO]  demo.service.batchservice.BatchService: Starting the runAnalyticTripsJob job
[ INFO]  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher: Job: [SimpleJob: [name=analyticTripsLoaderJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{analyticTripFilename=ANALYTIC_TRIPS-30052022-175840.858.csv, time=T15:58:40.858902Z, isNewAnalyticTripNeeded=true}]
[ INFO]  org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler: Executing step: [retrievingDataStep]
[ INFO]  demo.service.demo.DemoDataRetriever: analyticTripFilename = ANALYTIC_TRIPS-30052022-175840.858.csv, isNewAnalyticTripNeeded = true
[ INFO]  demo.client.DemoAuthClient: Successfully accrued demo token
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.1: | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.2: | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.3: | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.3: | request(unbounded)
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.2: | request(unbounded)
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.1: | request(unbounded)
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.1: | onNext(<200,Flux.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.handlerEntityFlux(DefaultWebClient.java:635),[access-control-allow-origin:"*", x-request-id:"xyz", content-disposition:"attachment; filename="data.csv.gz"", ... function-execution-id:"j", x-cloud-trace-context:"xxx;o=1", Connection:"close", Content-Length:"68", Content-Type:"application/octet-stream", Via:"1.1 google"]>)
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.2: | onNext(<200,Flux.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.handlerEntityFlux(DefaultWebClient.java:635),[access-control-allow-origin:"*", x-request-id:"xyz", content-disposition:"attachment; filename="data.csv.gz"", ... function-execution-id:"j", x-cloud-trace-context:"xxx;o=1", Connection:"close", Content-Length:"68", Content-Type:"application/octet-stream", Via:"1.1 google"]>)
[ INFO]  demo.service.demo.LocalFileManager: LocalFileManager saving ./tmp/ANALYTIC_TRIPS-30052022-175840.858.csv
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.3: | onNext(Mono.log ⇢ at demo.service.demo.DemoDataRetriever.lambda$execute$0(DemoDataRetriever.java:45))
[ INFO]  demo.service.demo.DemoDataRetriever: LocalFileManager saved ANALYTIC_TRIPS-30052022-175840.858.csv
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.2: | onComplete()
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.3: | onComplete()
[ INFO]  reactor.Mono.OnAssembly.1: | onComplete()
[ INFO]  org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep: Step: [retrievingDataStep] executed in 2s257ms
[ INFO]  org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler: Executing step: [processingDataStep]
[ INFO]  demo.config.BatchConfiguration: analyticTripFilename = ANALYTIC_TRIPS-30052022-175840.858.csv
[ INFO]  demo.service.demo.LocalFileManager: LocalFileManager getFileResource ./tmp/ANALYTIC_TRIPS-30052022-175840.858.csv
[ERROR]  org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep: Encountered an error executing step processingDataStep in job analyticTripsLoaderJob
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the part where you read the file from S3? I don't see how/where these steps are chained after each other. Anyway, my first guess is that you are bit by the different nature of CompletableFuture and Mono. While Mono is lazy (not executed until subscription), CompleatableFuture is eager (executed as soon as it is created). Make sure to use it like this: `Mono.fromFuture(() -> s3AsyncClient.getObject(...))` to make it lazy.

Comment: The first snippet of code is taken from the first step of a Spring Batch flow (return RepeatStatus.FINISHED just update the status of this step). The next Spring Batch step (not reported) is the step that read the uploaded file and elaborate it.

Comment: In a sequential flow, Spring Batch will start a given step only when the previous step has finished successfully. The behaviour you are seeing is related to the reactive code (even though I see you are using `.block()`), probably running in a background thread. The same behaviour should happen outside of a Spring Batch job.

Comment: For local development, I uses a different implementation of MyFileManager.java interface that saves files on my pc. Everything works well calling the same external service.

Comment: I'm wrong...also the local implementation run out into a 'Input resource must exist'. It happens now that I switched from a synch to an asyn implementation. I cannot figure out why given the .block()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved...it was just a matter of turning *map* into *flatMap* in the tasklet:

---

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> response = myService.getAnalyticsDataBuffer2(authToken);
response.flatMap(e -> {
    DataBufferMapper dataBufferMapper = new DataBufferMapper(myFileManager, analyticTripFilename);
    return dataBufferMapper.apply(e);
}).block();
```

---

Now it works both locally and on S3.